# question related to conversion from NSDate to NSString

Tags: iphone

NSString *abc = @"2009-12-12 16:25:00";

i have 1 string in this format as shown above.

NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
now i want currentDate in also this format  as specified 2009-12-12 16:25:00

and also i want to convert this currentDate from NSdate to NSString format with specified thisformat 2009-12-12 16:25:00

help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString* golly = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSDateFormatter`.